# different between counterBuilder and histogramBuilder when you create graphe on monitor azur metric?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, metrics

hi i have question about custom metric .
i use this method

```
GlobalOpenTelemetry.getMeter("toto").counterBuilder("count").setUnit("milliseconds").build().add(Long.valueOf(2L);
GlobalOpenTelemetry.getMeter("toto").histogramBuilder("histo").setUnit("milliseconds").build().record(2.0);
```

when  i click on azur monitor ->supervision -> metric  i select the metric name  and i can see my graph .
count metric and "histo" metric are no different ?

other example  i use [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-add-modify?tabs=aspnetcore#collect-custom-telemetry)

```
  Meter meter = GlobalOpenTelemetry.getMeter("OTEL.AzureMonitor.Demo");

        LongCounter myFruitCounter = meter
                .counterBuilder("MyFruitCounter")
                .build();

        myFruitCounter.add(1, Attributes.of(AttributeKey.stringKey("name"), "apple", AttributeKey.stringKey("color"), "red"));
        myFruitCounter.add(2, Attributes.of(AttributeKey.stringKey("name"), "lemon", AttributeKey.stringKey("color"), "yellow"));
        myFruitCounter.add(1, Attributes.of(AttributeKey.stringKey("name"), "lemon", AttributeKey.stringKey("color"), "yellow"));
        myFruitCounter.add(2, Attributes.of(AttributeKey.stringKey("name"), "apple", AttributeKey.stringKey("color"), "green"));
        myFruitCounter.add(5, Attributes.of(AttributeKey.stringKey("name"), "apple", AttributeKey.stringKey("color"), "red"));
        myFruitCounter.add(4, Attributes.of(AttributeKey.stringKey("name"), "lemon", AttributeKey.stringKey("color"), "yellow"));
    }
```

i try to create my graphe in azur monitor  >supervision>metric  i can select my metric .
but when i create the graph i cannot see the label  apple and lemon .
maybe metric on azur its not to  create graph for metric :/.
how i can create this specfic graph i dont want to use grafana :)

i try the solution  and use microsoft azure website but the tutorial is not good  :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Counter** and **histogram** metrics serve different purposes. To see meaningful distinctions in the metrics in Azure Monitor, Adjusting the data collected and the visualization settings should help you see the differences more clearly. collecting and visualizing the data in a way that highlights their specific characteristics and purposes.

- Azure Monitor's native metric charts might not always show labels for individual data points when you have multiple dimensions or attributes attached to your metrics.

By using Azure Monitor Workbooks, we can visualize the "apple" and "lemon" labels alongside the metric values.

**Created Custom metrics:**

[image]

- After sending your metrics data with values to Azure Monitor, you can query these metrics in Azure Monitor Metrics Explorer or Logs.

**Use Metrics Explorer:**

- Select the metric ("MyFruitCounter") and use the "Group by" feature to group the data by the "name" and "color" dimensions. it creates separate lines or bars for each combination of "name" and "color,"

Create a **log query:**

[image]

- Write a custom query to group and aggregate data by values.

```
MyFruitCounter
| summarize SumValue = sum(CounterValue) by name, color
```

Use the grouping and aggregation capabilities in Metrics Explorer or Logs to visualize your data by these values.

Comment: thank you @Suresh-Chikkam for your answer  i understood